# How RabbitMQ delete message after consumed it or after TTL

Tags: rabbitmq

I read that rabbitmq store data on the file system according to https://www.rabbitmq.com/backup.html

I understand from here every published message will be stored to file system if it is persistence. Ok no problem.

But what happens when we consume the message? Or what happens after TTL?

Any idea?